# where to check the state of dynamically created checkboxes

Tags: asp.net

Hello in my programme I need to create dynamically checkboxlist with items - got from teh database.

The problem is when Clicking a button i should get the text from cn only checked checkboxes and I should redirect the user to another page

And I have difficulty with determining width of the controls are checkedore

1. if I checked immediately after they are added

   So if I write

> if (mycheckbox.Items[s].Selected==true)

after this line

```
  Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(mycheckbox);
```

they are not checked still so this will be always false)

1. On postback event (clicking the button ) - we know on  postback event dynamic controls  no longer exist)

**here is my code**

```
protected void ddlNumberTourists_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int numTourists = Convert.ToInt32(ddlNumberTourists.SelectedItem.Text);
    for (int i = 0; i < numTourists; i++)
    {
    string connectionString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=excursion;Trusted_Connection=true";
        string query =
  "SELECT Extra_Charge_ID, Excursion_ID, Amout, Extra_Charge_Description FROM EXTRA_CHARGES WHERE Excursion_ID=" + mynewstring;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int s = 0;
            while (rd.Read())
            {
                mycheckbox.ID = "chkblextracharge" + i.ToString() + s.ToString();
                mycheckbox.Items.Add(rd["Extra_Charge_Description"].ToString());
                Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(mycheckbox);
                s++;
            }


        }//End of try

        catch (Exception ex)
        { }


    }//end of for
```

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a client-side check using jQuery in my online Quiz engine (demo: http://webinfocentral.com): the extract from that code snippet follows:

```
var _rows = $(this).find('tr');

for (i = 0; i < _rows.length; i++) {

    // find out if checkbox is checked
    _checked = $(_rows[i]).find('input:checkbox').is(':checked');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int s = 0;
        mycheckboxList = new CheckBoxList();
        mycheckboxList.ID = "chkblextracharge" + i.ToString();
        while (rd.Read())
        {
            ListItem LI = new ListItem(rd["Extra_Charge_Description"].ToString(), s.ToString());
            LI.Selected = rd["Selected_Criteria"] == "TRUE";
            mycheckboxList.Items.Add(LI);

            s++;
        }
        Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(mycheckboxList);
```

Comment: I can't LI.Selected = rd["Selected_Criteria"] == TRUE" I don't have selected_criteria in my datareader. and where actually you test if this dynamically added checkboxes are checked! i want to store their text in session so i can use it in another form